# Getting error when fetching data from Sql server compact using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I converted my sql database to sql compact and now I am getting linq queries error in group and where clauses

Here is my query

```
from s in ServiceSheets
join b in Branches on s.BranchId equals b.Id
join r in Resellers on s.CustomerId equals r.Id
join add in Addresses on r.AddressId equals add.Id into address
from a in address.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.Name) || s.Name.ToLower().Contains(filters.Name.ToLower()))
&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.Customer) || r.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(filters.Customer.ToLower()) || r.LastName.ToLower().Contains(filters.Customer.ToLower()))
&& (filters.Status == "SelectAll" || (filters.Status == "Completed" && s.InvoiceNo > 0) || (filters.Status == "Pending" && s.InvoiceNo == null))
&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.BranchName) || b.Name.ToLower().Contains(filters.BranchName.ToLower()))
&& (s.ExpectedDate >= filters.FromDate && s.ExpectedDate <= filters.ToDate)
&& s.ApplicationId == CurrentApplicationId
&& (s.IsDeleted == null || s.IsDeleted == false)
select s
```

**Here is the sql query**

```
{SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Filter1].[Name1] AS [Name], 
    [Filter1].[Name2] AS [Name1], 
    [Filter1].[Id2] AS [Id1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[ExpectedDate] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__13 ELSE [Filter1].[ExpectedDate] END AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[ExpectedPrice] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[ExpectedPrice] END AS [C3], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[SerialNumber] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[SerialNumber] END AS [C4], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[InvoiceNo] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[InvoiceNo] END AS [C5], 
    [Filter1].[Description1] AS [Description], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsDeleted1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsDeleted1] END AS [C6], 
    @p__linq__14 AS [C7], 
    [Filter1].[Id3] AS [Id2], 
    [Filter1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Filter1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[DiscountPercentage] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[DiscountPercentage] END AS [C8], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[UpdatedBy1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__15 ELSE [Filter1].[UpdatedBy1] END AS [C9], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[UpdatedDate1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__16 ELSE [Filter1].[UpdatedDate1] END AS [C10], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[CreatedBy1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__17 ELSE [Filter1].[CreatedBy1] END AS [C11], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[CreatedDate1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__18 ELSE [Filter1].[CreatedDate1] END AS [C12], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsDeleted2] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsDeleted2] END AS [C13], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsShareable1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsShareable1] END AS [C14], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsSynced1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsSynced1] END AS [C15], 
    @p__linq__19 AS [C16], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Type] IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE [Filter1].[Type] END AS [C17], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__20 ELSE [Extent4].[Id] END AS [C18], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[AddressLine1] END AS [C19], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[AddressLine2] END AS [C20], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[City] END AS [C21], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[State] END AS [C22], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[ZipCode] END AS [C23], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[Country] END AS [C24], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[PhoneNo] END AS [C25], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[MobileNo] END AS [C26], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[Email] END AS [C27], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__21 WHEN ([Extent4].[UpdatedBy] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__22 ELSE [Extent4].[UpdatedBy] END AS [C28], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__23 WHEN ([Extent4].[UpdatedDate] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__24 ELSE [Extent4].[UpdatedDate] END AS [C29], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__25 WHEN ([Extent4].[CreatedBy] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__26 ELSE [Extent4].[CreatedBy] END AS [C30], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__27 WHEN ([Extent4].[CreatedDate] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__28 ELSE [Extent4].[CreatedDate] END AS [C31], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ([Extent4].[IsDeleted] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Extent4].[IsDeleted] END AS [C32], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ([Extent4].[IsShareable] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Extent4].[IsShareable] END AS [C33], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ([Extent4].[IsSynced] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Extent4].[IsSynced] END AS [C34], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__29 ELSE [Extent4].[ApplicationId] END AS [C35]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description1], [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], [Extent1].[ExpectedDate] AS [ExpectedDate], [Extent1].[ExpectedPrice] AS [ExpectedPrice], [Extent1].[InvoiceNo] AS [InvoiceNo], [Extent1].[SerialNumber] AS [SerialNumber], [Extent1].[ApplicationId] AS [ApplicationId1], [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted1], [Extent1].[BranchId] AS [BranchId1], [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name2], [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description2], [Extent2].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy2], [Extent2].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate2], [Extent2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy2], [Extent2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate2], [Extent2].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted3], [Extent2].[IsSynced] AS [IsSynced2], [Extent2].[IsShareable] AS [IsShareable2], [Extent2].[ApplicationId] AS [ApplicationId2], [Extent2].[AddressId] AS [AddressId1], [Extent2].[Logo] AS [Logo], [Extent2].[LogoType] AS [LogoType], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent3].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent3].[DiscountPercentage] AS [DiscountPercentage], [Extent3].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy1], [Extent3].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate1], [Extent3].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy1], [Extent3].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate1], [Extent3].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted2], [Extent3].[IsSynced] AS [IsSynced1], [Extent3].[IsShareable] AS [IsShareable1], [Extent3].[ApplicationId] AS [ApplicationId3], [Extent3].[AddressId] AS [AddressId2], [Extent3].[Type] AS [Type], [Extent3].[IdentificationId] AS [IdentificationId], [Extent3].[BranchId] AS [BranchId2]
        FROM   [ServiceSheet] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [Branch] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BranchId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [Reseller] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[CustomerId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] IS NULL) OR (0 = [Extent1].[IsDeleted]) ) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[AddressId2] = [Extent4].[Id]
    WHERE ((cast(@p__linq__0 as ntext) IS NULL) OR ((LEN(@p__linq__0)) = 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__1), LOWER([Filter1].[Name1]))) > 0)) AND ((cast(@p__linq__2 as ntext) IS NULL) OR ((LEN(@p__linq__2)) = 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__3), LOWER([Filter1].[FirstName]))) > 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__4), LOWER([Filter1].[LastName]))) > 0)) AND ((N'SelectAll' = @p__linq__5) OR ((N'Completed' = @p__linq__6) AND ([Filter1].[InvoiceNo] > cast(0 as float))) OR ((N'Pending' = @p__linq__7) AND ([Filter1].[InvoiceNo] IS NULL))) AND ((cast(@p__linq__8 as ntext) IS NULL) OR ((LEN(@p__linq__8)) = 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__9), LOWER([Filter1].[Name2]))) > 0)) AND ([Filter1].[ExpectedDate] >= @p__linq__10) AND ([Filter1].[ExpectedDate] <= @p__linq__11) AND ([Filter1].[ApplicationId1] = @p__linq__12)}
```

**Error**

**p__linq__7 : String truncation: max=7, len=9, value='SelectAll'**

I am getting the above error in both group clause and where clause. Can somebody please point me towards right direction?

Comment: Can you show the SQL?

Comment: Are you sure all the column lengths are the same in the converted database?

Comment: @Crowcoder I changed the length of other filter.status values. Like i changed completed to "completeddddddd" and pending to "pendinggggggg" and it started working. So what it is doing is that it assigns length to the shortest filter. How can I change that

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. Linq is great, but when I have something that complex I go with stored procedures.

Comment: @ErikEJ any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the SQL CE provider, try swapping the order:
 (filters.Status == "Completed" && s.InvoiceNo > 0) || (filters.Status == "Pending" && s.InvoiceNo == null) || filters.Status == "SelectAll"

Comment: @ErikEJ Still not working

Answer (score 0):

It may be that one of your column cannot accomodate the data, and is trying to fit 9 chars in a column that can only hold 7.

Comment: I changed the length of other filter.status values. Like i changed completed to "completeddddddd" and pending to "pendinggggggg" and it started working. So what it is doing is that it assigns length to the shortest filter. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `filters.Status == "SelectAll"` to `filters.Status.Contains("Select All")` and it worked for me in this case. Still  don't know how it will work if I want `filters.Status == "SelectAll"` or `filters.Status.Equals("SelectAll")`.

Here is the generated query with `filters.Status.Contains("Select All")`.

```
 SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
        [Filter1].[Name1] AS [Name], 
        [Filter1].[Name2] AS [Name1], 
        [Filter1].[Id2] AS [Id1], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[ExpectedDate] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__13 ELSE [Filter1].[ExpectedDate] END AS [C2], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[ExpectedPrice] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[ExpectedPrice] END AS [C3], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[SerialNumber] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[SerialNumber] END AS [C4], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[InvoiceNo] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[InvoiceNo] END AS [C5], 
        [Filter1].[Description1] AS [Description], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsDeleted1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsDeleted1] END AS [C6], 
        @p__linq__14 AS [C7], 
        [Filter1].[Id3] AS [Id2], 
        [Filter1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Filter1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[DiscountPercentage] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float) ELSE [Filter1].[DiscountPercentage] END AS [C8], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[UpdatedBy1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__15 ELSE [Filter1].[UpdatedBy1] END AS [C9], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[UpdatedDate1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__16 ELSE [Filter1].[UpdatedDate1] END AS [C10], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[CreatedBy1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__17 ELSE [Filter1].[CreatedBy1] END AS [C11], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[CreatedDate1] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__18 ELSE [Filter1].[CreatedDate1] END AS [C12], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsDeleted2] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsDeleted2] END AS [C13], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsShareable1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsShareable1] END AS [C14], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[IsSynced1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Filter1].[IsSynced1] END AS [C15], 
        @p__linq__19 AS [C16], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Type] IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE [Filter1].[Type] END AS [C17], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__20 ELSE [Extent4].[Id] END AS [C18], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[AddressLine1] END AS [C19], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[AddressLine2] END AS [C20], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[City] END AS [C21], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[State] END AS [C22], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[ZipCode] END AS [C23], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[Country] END AS [C24], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[PhoneNo] END AS [C25], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[MobileNo] END AS [C26], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent4].[Email] END AS [C27], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__21 WHEN ([Extent4].[UpdatedBy] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__22 ELSE [Extent4].[UpdatedBy] END AS [C28], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__23 WHEN ([Extent4].[UpdatedDate] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__24 ELSE [Extent4].[UpdatedDate] END AS [C29], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__25 WHEN ([Extent4].[CreatedBy] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__26 ELSE [Extent4].[CreatedBy] END AS [C30], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__27 WHEN ([Extent4].[CreatedDate] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__28 ELSE [Extent4].[CreatedDate] END AS [C31], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ([Extent4].[IsDeleted] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Extent4].[IsDeleted] END AS [C32], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ([Extent4].[IsShareable] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Extent4].[IsShareable] END AS [C33], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN cast(0 as bit) WHEN ([Extent4].[IsSynced] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Extent4].[IsSynced] END AS [C34], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[ApplicationId] IS NULL)) THEN @p__linq__29 ELSE [Extent4].[ApplicationId] END AS [C35]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description1], [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], [Extent1].[ExpectedDate] AS [ExpectedDate], [Extent1].[ExpectedPrice] AS [ExpectedPrice], [Extent1].[InvoiceNo] AS [InvoiceNo], [Extent1].[SerialNumber] AS [SerialNumber], [Extent1].[ApplicationId] AS [ApplicationId1], [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted1], [Extent1].[BranchId] AS [BranchId1], [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name2], [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description2], [Extent2].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy2], [Extent2].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate2], [Extent2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy2], [Extent2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate2], [Extent2].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted3], [Extent2].[IsSynced] AS [IsSynced2], [Extent2].[IsShareable] AS [IsShareable2], [Extent2].[ApplicationId] AS [ApplicationId2], [Extent2].[AddressId] AS [AddressId1], [Extent2].[Logo] AS [Logo], [Extent2].[LogoType] AS [LogoType], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent3].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent3].[DiscountPercentage] AS [DiscountPercentage], [Extent3].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy1], [Extent3].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate1], [Extent3].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy1], [Extent3].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate1], [Extent3].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted2], [Extent3].[IsSynced] AS [IsSynced1], [Extent3].[IsShareable] AS [IsShareable1], [Extent3].[ApplicationId] AS [ApplicationId3], [Extent3].[AddressId] AS [AddressId2], [Extent3].[Type] AS [Type], [Extent3].[IdentificationId] AS [IdentificationId], [Extent3].[BranchId] AS [BranchId2]
            FROM   [ServiceSheet] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [Branch] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BranchId] = [Extent2].[Id]
            INNER JOIN [Reseller] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[CustomerId] = [Extent3].[Id]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] IS NULL) OR (0 = [Extent1].[IsDeleted]) ) AS [Filter1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[AddressId2] = [Extent4].[Id]
        WHERE ((cast(@p__linq__0 as ntext) IS NULL) OR ((LEN(@p__linq__0)) = 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__1), LOWER([Filter1].[Name1]))) > 0)) AND ((cast(@p__linq__2 as ntext) IS NULL) OR ((LEN(@p__linq__2)) = 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__3), LOWER([Filter1].[FirstName]))) > 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__4), LOWER([Filter1].[LastName]))) > 0)) AND ((@p__linq__5 LIKE N'%Select All%') OR ((@p__linq__6 LIKE N'%Completed%') AND ([Filter1].[InvoiceNo] > cast(0 as float))) OR ((@p__linq__7 LIKE N'%Pending%') AND ([Filter1].[InvoiceNo] IS NULL))) AND ((cast(@p__linq__8 as ntext) IS NULL) OR ((LEN(@p__linq__8)) = 0) OR ((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__9), LOWER([Filter1].[Name2]))) > 0)) AND ([Filter1].[ExpectedDate] >= @p__linq__10) AND ([Filter1].[ExpectedDate] <= @p__linq__11) AND ([Filter1].[ApplicationId1] = @p__linq__12)
```

**We should better use `filters.Status.StartsWith("Select All")` for better performance.**